# ActiveModel serializer ignores root key when posts or post is empty or nil

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

I am using active model serializer V0.10.0 with Rails 5 api only application. During implementation I noticed the AMS is completely ignoring the root key when the posts/post is empty or nil respectively. This behavior actually breaks my mobile app as it always expects root key data in all response.

So what I want to achieve here is no matter what I always want `data` as root element of my Rails app response for all requests.

Response for SHOW API when the post is empty

```
SHOW render json: @post, root: 'data'
```

Expected

```
{
  "data": {}
}
```

Actual

```
null
```

Response for INDEX API when the posts are empty

```
INDEX render json: @posts, root: 'data'
```

Expected

```
{
  "data": []
}
```

Actual

```
{
  "posts": []
}
```

```
class ApplicationSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json
  def host
    Rails.application.secrets.dig(:host_url)
  end
end
```

```
class PostSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :id
  has_many :comments
end
```

Comment: can you post your serializer class definition?

Comment: @lacostenycoder: I have updated my post with ApplicationSerializer & PostSerializer. Thanks!

Comment: Is this unexpected behavior according to the ActiveModel Serializer documentation? Where is `@post` being set? Is it `nil`? What happens if you set `@post = {}` first?